# How to set context in alexa

Tags: chatbot, alexa-skills-kit

I worked on Dialogflow where I have set the context for my intent but don't know how to set the context in Alexa

```
user: open demo bot
alexa: welcome! How can I help you?

User: update my name
Alexa: What's your name?

User: Jason
Alexa: your name is updated as Jason, Anything else?

user: John
Alexa: your name is updated as John, Anything else?
```

it should give an error but it directly updates the name (John).

example 2

```
user: open demo bot
alexa: welcome! How can I help you? (WelcomeIntent)

user: order food
alexa: We offer item1, item2. What you would like to have? (FoodItemIntent)

user: item2
alexa: you have ordered item2, your order will be served soon. (OrderFoodIntent)
```

food ordering session completed here

now if user again says any food item like

```
user: item1
alexa: you have ordered item1, your order will be served soon. (OrderFoodIntent)
```

it should not directly update the ordered item it should prompt an error message like "I didn't get that, you can ask me to order food or update name"

as the food order session has been completed.

Comment: You can use ```Intent Confirmation``` or ```Slot Confirmation``` In  Alexa to make sure if the user really wants to change his name again so, based on his input you can do whatever you want.

Comment: I don't want to confirm the name, I want that if the user wants to update his name then alexa must trigger UpdateNameIntent not the UpdatedNameHandler intent

Comment: So What you are saying is he should get a response like whether he wants to change the name if it is already set. Am I understanding it right??

Comment: @sharankenam  I have updated my question with another example hope it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

In Alexa, it currently not possible as easily as it is in Dialogflow. But you can play with the server-side, where you can simulate context.

For example, in Alexa's response/request, you will store intent history and values. Based on that you can build context on the server-side. Like when you receive intent that doesn't fit the context, you will send user reprompt to say whatever you need. For that, I recommend some general intents like text_intent which matches the text, or number_intent for numbers and so...

Or if you can put it to a different level when you somehow get what have user asked (not intent), then the sentence will be sent do dialogflow NLU API, and based on the sentence you will get context answer.